# Вычитание двоичных чисел, strtol. C++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, мне нужно вывести разность двух двоичных чисел с помощью функции strtol. Код я  написал но мне выводит в 10 сс, а надо в 2-ой. Не подскажите, как исправить?

```
void Diff(string bin1, string bin2)
{
    cout << strtol(bin1.c_str(), NULL, 2) - strtol(bin2.c_str(), NULL, 2) << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

где `bin1`и `bin2` двоичные числа. При этом нужно именно этой командой вывести, а не сделать перевод после вычитания...

Comment: В смысле - через `cout`, не переводя в строку? таких флагов, насколько я помню, не предусмотрено...

Comment: для двоичной системы нет

Answer (score 1):

`std::setbase` из `<iomanip>` - для двоичной системы не работает. Практически единственный вариант вывода напрямую вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

void Diff(string bin1, string bin2) {
  cout << bitset<8>(strtol(bin1.c_str(), NULL, 2) - strtol(bin2.c_str(), NULL, 2)) << endl;
}

int main() {
  Diff("111111","11");
  return 0;
}
```

Но при этом "висят" начальные нули, которые зависят от применяемой разрядности битсета. Если нужно отрезать незначащие нули слева - можно [глянуть тут](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/154369/).